# Adding/Installing debugger to Qt Designer on Mac OS

Tags: macos, qt, debugging, qt-creator

I really get desperated. I'm trying to get the debugger installed on Qt creator, but after hours/days I still don't have a clue what to do.

The Qt creator and qt librarys work well. Now I downloaded the Debugger library for mac (http://qt-project.org/downloads). Then I executed the downloaded file. But I really don't know where the libraries stored now (How to know?) So I don't know what source path to use in **Tools > Options > Debugger > General > Add**. Neither I know what path to choose for target path.

Then I read to add the debugger to the kit on: **Tools > Options > Build and Run > Kits.** I choose the downloaded file from above. But then I get an error *"File is not executable"*.

I absolutly don't know which files/path to choose on which position. Can someone help me? I searched for the libraries in /urs/lib and found 3 files:

```
libQtCLucene_debug.4.8.dylib -> libQtCLucene_debug.4.8.5.dylib
libQtCLucene_debug.4.dylib -> libQtCLucene_debug.4.8.5.dylib
libQtCLucene_debug.dylib -> libQtCLucene_debug.4.8.5.dylib
```

But are those the only ones got installed by installing the donwloaded file? And where to set the path?

Sorry if I sound desperated, I really am ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debug libraries aren't a debugger. As far as I am aware, since Apple removed gdb from OS X Mavericks, Qt Creator doesn't have a debugger it can use.  I believe there is a alpha version of Qt Creator that uses lldb. You can also buy Intels C compiler which comes with gdb. Or try and build gdb yourself. I don't think there currently is a good solution.

Comment: Okay thank you for your quick response. I now installed gdb. But now I don't know how to connect this to qt creator. I used following instruction to install gdb [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/gnu_debugger/installing_gdb.htm)

Comment: okay i found an easy instruction to install debugger (gdb) in qt creator on following [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720591/how-do-i-make-qt-creators-debugger-show-the-contents-of-c-vectors-in-os-x) it solved my problem after hours of desperation :)